# How to apply 'like' or '=' filters livewire component?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I want to filter data by using 'like' or '=' but I do not want to expose them directly in the view because it is easy to manipulate form view, this is my render method:

```
public function render(){
        $bc = BC::query();
        $bc = $bc->where($this->option, $this->condition,$this->searchString)->get();
        return view('livewire.customer', [
            'bCs' => $bc,
        ]);
    }
```

This is my front element, and it will not working when I use the `like`.

```
<select wire:model="condition" class="form-control">
    <option value="like">Like</option>
    <option value="=">=</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the best approach but it's  working for me.

```
public $sign ;
if($this->condition == 'like')
{
    $this->sign = '%';
}else if($this->condition == '='){
    $this->sign = '';
}else{
    $this->sign = '%';
    $this->condition = 'like'
}
public function render(){
   $bc = BC::query();
   $bc = $bc->where($this->option, $this->condition,$this->sign.$this->searchString.$this->sign)->get();
        return view('livewire.customer', [
            'bCs' => $bc,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: but you are still checking the `like` by condition from view

Comment: @Nazari I updated my answer. now this script is act like validation and if some manipulate form view it's not executes

Answer (score 4):

You can check the value of **$this->condition** property, if it is what you have defined in the view then do the filtering and if it is not then don't.

```
public function render(){
    $bc = BC::query();
    $condition_field = null;
    
    if ($this->condition == 'like') {
        $condition_field = 'like';
        $sign = '%';
    } 
    else if ($this->condition == '=') {
        $condition_field = '=';
        $sign = '';
    } 
    
    if($condition_field) {
        $bc = $bc->where($this->option, $condition_field, $sign . $this->searchString . $sign);
    }
    return view('livewire.customer', [
        'bCs' => $bc->get(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: also, you are still checking the like by condition from view

Comment: Yes it still checks from view but prevents SQL Injection.

Comment: the `$sign ` is not working for `like`